# Separate and restrict data access using schemas

Tags: postgresql

I am an Oracle DBA, new to PostgreSQL. I have a requirement to separate some modules data, so that one module will not have access to read the data of another module. 
I read about the use of schemas in PostgreSql which is somewhat different than the use of it in Oracle. However seems like it is recommended to use the method of different schemas for separation and management - just like in Oracle.
 However, when I create 2 schemas - connected to the same database and same user - I can do a select from the other schema's table. 
That is, for example, if I have schema A owning table a, and schema B owning table b, when I set the search path to schema B I can do a select on schema’s A table a without any problem.
 I couldn't find a way to revoke this privilege from schema B.
The only I could find  then to separate access to data, is using different roles, that is to create role A with schema A, and role B with schema B. then I can grant and revoke access from user B in order for it to see what I want from role's A tables.

Is this correct? Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you thought of using separate databases instead?

Comment: @sibert: as long as Tamar is only using one user, different databases won't help either, as the user is global to all databases. And ownership is on user level.

Comment: Thank you very much @a_horse_with_no_name. That is what I thought, but needed to make sure. I must confess then that I do not understand why use separate schemas connecting the same user... Is it to enable objects duplicity (that is, to be able to create, for example,  the same table  with the same name but under a different search path)?

Comment: @Tamar: the "pattern" one schema per user is exactly what Oracle uses.

Answer (score 1):

> *if I have schema A owning table a*

A schema does not "own" a table in Postgres - a **user** does. This is the same as in Oracle - the difference (and maybe where your confusion arises) is that in Oracle in a regular user can't create tables outside of a schema that has the same name as the user account.

So if user `arthur` creates a table in schema_a and one in schema_b, both tables are owned by `arthur` - **not** "the schema".

If you used different schemas/users in Oracle to separate data and to prevent access to the other user's tables, then you need two users and two schemas in Postgres as well.

The default [`search_path`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) in Postgres is setup in a way, that (unqualified) tables are always first searched (and created) in a schema with the same name as the user running the statement.

So if you create two users and a schema with the user's name for each user, you pretty much have the same setup as in Oracle:

```
create user arthur with password 'foobar';
create schema arthur authorization arthur; --<< this is what Oracle does "automatically"
create user bob with password 'verysecret';
create schema bob authorization bob;
```

Now, if bob creates a table, that table is created in the schema `bob` and is owned by the user `bob`. User `arthur` has not privileges to access that table.

---

If you never need to share data between those users (or schemas), then you can create two databases, create two users and let both users create everything in the `public` schema of "their" database.

Comment: This feels very hacky to have the schema named by user name as opposed to purpose

Comment: @AvinKavish: that's not hacky at all. It goes along with the default search_path and mimics Oracle's behaviour (which is what Tamar is confused about).